# How to configure ARR - Application Request Routing - to run both as web server and as as a gateway or proxy?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, arr

I have this IIS7.5 with ARR installed on and configured as a reverse proxy to another server which is running IIS7.

On this IIS7.5 I have ASP.NET 4 applications and simple websites installed.

Since configuring a farm on this IIS7.5 running it as a reversed proxy, the local application doesn't run with this error message:

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

Will it be possible to run both local application and routing (reverse proxy) at the same time on this IIS7.5 or should I give up and move the applications to another server?